# Enter multiple datasets (Inputs) then print

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a program that will take three different inputs of data. 1st Student Number, 2nd A Mark, 3rd B Mark. Once the data has been entered the program will loop again and ask for the 1st input (Student Number) and so on. Once the user has entered in there desired sets of data they can break the loop by entering 0 on the 1st input (Student Number) as this marks the beginning on a new set of data.

How would I have it print out the multiple datasets that the user had entered?

This is how the input and output should look:

Program Input:

```
Student Number: --> 12345678
A Mark: --> 30
B Mark: --> 60
Student Number: --> 62445677
A Mark: --> 40
B Mark: --> 70
Student Number: --> 0
```

Expected output:

```
sn = 12345678 B = 60 A = 30 mark = 33.0
sn = 62445677 B = 70 A = 40 mark = 33.0
```

So far only 1 dataset can be printed out:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;
public class test
{
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

        // 0 To end the loop and run output! Repeats until 0 is entered!
        // Arraylist for each of the Vars!
        // Validation

        // Have to initialise - 1 So it doesn't terminate
        int studentNumber = 1;
        int studentNumberPassed = 12;

        int aMark = 0;
        int bMark = 0;

        int markTotal;
        double markAverage;

        boolean terminate = false;


        while (terminate == false) {
            studentNumber = reader.nextInt();
            if (studentNumber == 0) {
                terminate = true;
                break;
            }
            // Once 0 is inputted to terminate it overwrites.
            studentNumberPassed = studentNumber;
            aMark = reader.nextInt();
            bMark = reader.nextInt();
        }

        markTotal = aMark +  bMark;
        // Cast to double before calculating
        markAverage = (double) markTotal / 2;

        //Can also use out.format
        System.out.printf("sn = %d ex = %d cw = %d mark = %.1f",
            studentNumberPassed, aMark, bMark, markAverage);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Enter multiple datasets (Inputs) then print

It's satisfy your input and output result, However there is so many way to achieve multiple datasets (Inputs) then print.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
    private static List<String> storeResult;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        // 0 To end the loop and run output! Repeats until 0 is entered!
        // Arraylist for each of the Vars!
        // Validation
        int studentNumber = 1; //Have to initialise - 1 So it doesn't terminate 
        int studentNumberPassed = 12;
        int cwMark = 0;
        int examMark = 0;

        boolean terminate = false;
        storeResult = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (terminate == false) {
            System.out.print("Student Number: --> ");
            studentNumber = reader.nextInt();
            if (studentNumber == 0) { // Once 0 is inputted to terminate it overwrites.
                terminate = true;
                displayResult();
                return;
            }

            studentNumberPassed = studentNumber; 
            System.out.print("CW Mark: --> ");
            cwMark = reader.nextInt();
            System.out.print("EX Mark: --> ");
            examMark = reader.nextInt();
            result(studentNumberPassed, cwMark, examMark);
        }
    }

    private static void result(int studentNumberPassed, int cwMark, int examMark) {
        int markTotal;
        double markAverage;
        markTotal = examMark + cwMark;
        // Cast to double before calculating
        markAverage = (double) markTotal / 2;
        String str = "sn = " + studentNumberPassed + " ex = " + examMark + " cw = " + cwMark + " mark = " + markAverage;
        storeResult.add(str);

    }

    private static void displayResult() {
        for(int data=0;data<storeResult.size();data++){
            System.out.println(""+storeResult.get(data));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Explanation

Currently you are **overwriting** the fields `studentNumberPassed`, `examMark` and `cwMark` **in every iteration**. That is also why in the end only the data of the last read student are saved and thus you only output the last student.

---

### Solution

You need to store the data in some kind of **collection**. Alternatively you could **directly output** the data **while iterating**.

For collections there is the `Collection` ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html)) interface in Java, with subcategories like `List` ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html)) and `Set` ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html)) (among others). A `List` would be good for your needs, for example a `LinkedList` ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html)).

---

### Container

Such a collection contains objects. You need some container object which holds all data for a student. Let us first design this container class:

```
public class StudentData {
    // Member variables for all data
    public int mStudentNumber;
    public int mCwMark;
    public int mExamMark;

    // A constructor setting all data
    public StudentData(int studentNumber, int cwMark, int examMark) {
        // Pass the data to the members variables
        this.mStudentNumber = studentNumber;
        this.mCwMark = cwMark;
        this.mExamMark = examMark;
    }
}
```

Note that for a good design we would make the member variables `private` and use `getter` methods for access. But for simplicity we just drop that here.

---

### Collect data

Now we build the `LinkedList` and collect all data:

```
// Create an empty list
final LinkedList<StudentData> dataList = new LinkedList<>();

// Iterate and collect
while (terminate == false) {
    studentNumber = reader.nextInt();
    if (studentNumber == 0) {
        terminate = true;
        break;
    }
    studentNumberPassed = studentNumber;
    cwMark = reader.nextInt();
    examMark = reader.nextInt();

    // Create container and pass values
    final StudentData studentData = new StudentData(studentNumberPassed, cwMark, examMark);

    // Add the container to the list
    dataList.add(studentData);
}
```

---

### Output data

Now all what is left is to iterate the container and output the data:

```
// A "for-each" loop which elegantly iterates all elements in a collection
for (final StudentData studentData : dataList) {
    markTotal = studentData.mExamMark + studentData.mCwMark;
    markAverage = (double) markTotal / 2;

    System.out.printf("sn = %d ex = %d cw = %d mark = %.1f",
        studentData.mStudentNumber,
        studentData.mExamMark,
        studentData.mCwMark,
        markAverage);
}
```